# How to create a folder with 2 .txt in it - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, script, notepad++

I want to write a script to do the following:

- Create a folder with the name I specify each time I run the script
- Create two .txt files in the same folder

For now I'm using the following:

```
@echo off
    break>"CSR.txt"
    break>"KEY.txt"
```

The problem is that I still have to make the directories myself, drag the script into that folder and then run it. As my script and all the folders it will create will be located in the "My Documents" folder I can just run the script from there.

Optionally I would like to let Notepad++ open both text files after they have been created.

I've tried to find the answers on Google and browsed through numerous posts but can't find the answer.

Comment: Hints: [`set /p`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to ask for the directory name, [`md`](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) to create the directory, `cd` to change to the directory, you know how to create the files.

Comment: Is `break` an actual command or you just type it as a placeholder before `>` redirection operator? I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 of this script is done thanks to some help I got via Facebook:

```
@echo off
set /p Folder= locatie nieuwe map?
mkdir %Folder%
cd %Folder%
break>"CSR.txt"
break>"KEY.txt"
start notepad++ "CSR.txt"
start notepad++ "KEY.txt"
```

Onwards to V2!